# Creating new Role in asp.net core using ado.net

Tags: asp.net-core

We are designed our custom class to configure Asp.net core 2.1. User Registration is working fine but .In creating role and assigning role we are facing issue , Controller action gives  me object set to reference error , I am not why this giving it .
We are using ado.net as database connection . Can you please help in this

AccountController :

```cs
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult CreateRole(ApplicationRole applicationRole)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result =  _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("SuperAdmin"));
    }
    return View();
}
```

Store Method : RoleStore.cs

```cs
public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationRole role, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
        role.Id = await connection.QuerySingleAsync<int>($@"INSERT INTO [ApplicationRole] ([Name], [NormalizedName])
            VALUES (@{nameof(ApplicationRole.Name)}, @{nameof(ApplicationRole.NormalizedName)});
            SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)", role);
    }

    return IdentityResult.Success;
}
```

Comment: hi - can you post the error so we have more exact info?

Comment: It is giving  "object set reference" on this line : _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("SuperAdmin"));

Comment: do you mean it says `object reference not set to an instance of an object`? If so that suggests `_roleManager` hasn't been pulled in to your controller correctly. Try debugging w/ a break point on that line. You can hover over the object or set a watch to see what its current value is.